# pyunit mock sys.argv in other file

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito, parameter-passing

I have one python file wrote like this:

```
import sys
cfgfile = sys.argv[1]
cfg = ConfigObj(cfgfile)
db_dbname=cfg.get("DB_NAME")
class UserMappingsLoader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.debug = 0
        self.cuStartTime = 0
        self.fiId = 0
```

and I want to write a pyunit to do the testing for one method in this code. But when I run my testing code, it shows:

```
cfgfile = sys.argv[1]
list index out of range
```

Anyone know how to mock the sys.argv from testing file to this file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using `patch` from the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) module. Here is an example:

```
from mock import patch

def test_your_function():
    fake_args = [None, "myfakearg"]
    with patch('sys.argv', fake_args):
        import yourmodule
        # rest of your test
```